# Python passing arguments from console

Tags: python

In the following code:

```
def foo(n):
  print "n value before if:",n #displays given num
  if n <= 2:
    print "n value:",n #not displayed even n is less than 2
num = raw_input()
print foo(num)
```

The `if` statement does not execute on giving inputs less than 2 for `num`.

So, why is `if` statement not executing?

Comment: `num` is a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

raw_input returns a string, you are then comparing it to an integer.

Try converting it to an int:

```
num = int(raw_input())
```